# How to use flutter provider in main.dart

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

This is my code  of my main.dart where I wrapping with multiprovider also using socket io . I want that as soons as socket payload comes provider list is populated with the data

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import './providers/socket_data_provider.dart';
import 'package:wineasy/screens/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:wineasy/screens/test.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://localhost:4848', <String, dynamic>{
    'transports': ['websocket'],
    'autoConnect': false
  });

  late BuildContext _providerContext;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    connectToSocketServer(context);
  }

  void connectToSocketServer(BuildContext context) {
    // Store the context in a variable
    _providerContext = context;

    socket.connect();

    socket.onConnect((data) {
      print('connected');

      socket.on('orderToKitchen', (orders) async {
        // Access the SocketDataProvider and set the socket data using the stored context
        Provider.of<SocketDataProvider>(_providerContext, listen: false)
            .setSocketData(orders);

        // Play the sound when order arrives
        await player.play(AssetSource('music/alertTone1.mp3'));
      });
    });

    socket.onDisconnect((data) => {print('disconnected')});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SocketDataProvider()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.red),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home: const Scaffold(
          body: Test(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this `Provider.of<SocketDataProvider>(_providerContext, listen: false) .setSocketData(orders);` in **socket.on** is giving error

I want to save the incoming order to provider and use that is other screens.
Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are handling the provider context wrong, instead of storing the context in a variable and using it later, consider using a callback or a notifier to trigger changes in your provider, something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;
import './providers/socket_data_provider.dart';
import 'package:wineasy/screens/test.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late IO.Socket socket;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeSocket();
  }

  void initializeSocket() {
    socket = IO.io('http://localhost:4848', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'autoConnect': false,
    });

    socket.onConnect((_) {
      print('Connected to socket server');
    });

    socket.on('orderToKitchen', (data) {
      // Use Provider to update the socket data
      context.read<SocketDataProvider>().setSocketData(data);
    });

    socket.onDisconnect((_) => print('Disconnected from socket server'));

    socket.connect();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SocketDataProvider()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.red),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home: const Scaffold(
          body: Test(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and in you socketDataProvider:

```
    class SocketDataProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<dynamic> socketData = [];

  void setSocketData(dynamic data) {
    // Add new data to the list
    socketData.add(data);
    // Notify listeners about the change
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

and to get the SocketData simply use:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Access the provider
    final socketData = Provider.of<SocketDataProvider>(context).socketData;

    // Use socketData(depending on the data, here it is a string)
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: socketData.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(socketData[index].toString()),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: This is my code in socket
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SocketDataProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<dynamic> socketData = [];

  void setSocketData(List<dynamic> data) {
    final index = socketData.length;
    socketData.add(data);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
`
can you help with it
also show me how to handle it in the main.dart

Comment: I updated my answer, hope this helps more